# XPAGES: Link name using getelementbyid

Tags: xpages

How can I get the label of the link that is clicked by the user?

I have tried:

```
var elem=document.getElementById("#{id:link1}");var lbl=elem.label;
```

But this is not returning the label name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "label" property of a Link control is called text so the following server-side Javascript will get you the value of the label of the link and store the value in the variable "label":

```
var linkControl = getComponent("linkExample");
var label = linkControl.getText();
```

Comment: thanks.It worked on SSJS.
I was able to do on client JS as follows. var id = "#{id:link1}";
alert(dojo.byId(id).text);

Comment: As a follow on from this. This is a common piece of code. I would recommend getting the XPages cheat sheet from http://xpagescheatsheet.com/ .

Answer (score 2):

In Xpages [xp:label] tags turn into [span] tags so on csjs you have to use the innerHTML to get the value so your original code would have worked had it been.

`var elem=document.getElementById("#{id:link1}");`

var lbl=elem.innerHTML;